# GDB and DDD incomplete type

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger

I have read and not understood the current available material.  I only installed Linux last spring and taught myself how to program C++ at that time as well.  I am very new to this.

I am trying to debug a program which is using the [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/) package of matrix solvers.  I have variable types of the [Epetra_SerialDenseMatrix](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/r6.0/packages/epetra/doc/html/classEpetra__SerialDenseMatrix.html).  Neither [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) not [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) can display the contents of these variable types.

How, specifically do I get `gdb` and/or `ddd` to link to the Trilinos libraries so that these types of variables can be printed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through these [Trilinos tutorials](https://code.google.com/p/trilinos/wiki/TrilinosHandsOnTutorial)?

Also I found [this page](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/dev/packages/stk/doc/html/stk__mesh__testing__and__debugging.html) that shows how to use GDB or [Totalview](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx) to debug the unit tests that are shipped with Trilinos.

#### Excerpt from Trilinos page

- Serial debugging can be done in gdb or totalview

  - GDB

    - gdb
    - `% run -- --gtest_filter=<failing-test>`
- Debugging memory problems can be done with valgrind

  - In serial: `valgrind <utest-exe> -- --gtest_filter=<failing-test>`